# Video can't re-load when hosting on AWS's S3 + CloudFare

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, react-native-video

## Current behavior

Videos can't re-start (infinite "buffering") when using videos hosted on AWS's S3 + cached by CloudFlare. The same video hosted on another simple web server loads just fine each time, no matter how many times I try removing/adding the video component, or restarting the app.

Other android player in a native app works just fine for the same videos, iOS loads fine as well.

## Reproduction steps

Reproducible each time, but only in particular circumstances, or state of the cloud/cache (e.g I can reproduce it consistently in Poland, in the morning, but I cannot reproduce it in the afternoon).

Steps:

1. upload the same file to AWS S3 + CloudFare and to a simple webserver.
2. Start an app with 2 video components in the main view (example project attached)
3. Videos start playing
4. Get out of the app using "back" button, open the app again (or just remove the view and add it back again without closing the app)
5. Repeat 3 & 4 few times

Result: the video hosted on AWS S3 + CloudFare stops starting after 1st or few times, other video starts fine each and every time.

Video recording reproducing the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wfxr6GkZFfP2-WM4hHSfiiwYBritt4mN/view

Example project used to reproduce issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/files/2556644/bug_infinite_buffering_src.zip

Log file: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/files/2556678/bug_infinite_buffering_log.log

## Expected behavior

Videos should start each and every time.

## Platform

- Android ExoPlayer (react-native-video component)
- react-native 0.56.0
- react-native-video 3.2.1

Loads fine:

- https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_20mb.mp4
- http://handcraftedmobile.com/sample_dev_videos/bunny.mp4
- https://handcraftedmobile.com/sample_dev_videos/bunny.mp4
- https://handcraftedmobile.com/sample_dev_videos/bunny-big.mp4

Has trouble reloading:

- https://vid.twinbody.com/1811/bunny-big.mp4
- https://vid.twinbody.com/1811/bunny.mp4
- and other private videos hosted the same way as the one above

Please help finding the issue, any suggestions how to debug it appreciated.